# Use folium with locally saved tiles, weird behaviour

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I am trying to use folium in jupyter with locally saved tiles.

```py
tileset = 'file:///C:/Users/Daniel K/Pictures/Light_Map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
m = folium.Map(tiles=tileset,zoom_start=0,max_zoom=3,min_zoom=1, attr='Test',no_wrap=True)
```

When I run the code the map gets drawn most of the time **only** when zoomed in totally. Zooming out one level shows a blank background.
Weirdly enough sometimes all levels work, but a second later the problem returns - most of the time when zooming in again.

Also, even though "no_wrap" was set, the map wraps around.

I tried changing arguments, different max and min zoom levels, nothing worked.

I can provide the offline tileset for testing if you want, it is not very big (around 3 MB).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think You must download the full map around 50 GB !

https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/tileset/osm/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I generated the map tiles myself using a program that processed a map picture (jpg in my case) for use with a tile based map system. So there is no "full" map other than the tiles I generated - which look to be complete, as far as I unterstand the structure of the tile system